# Selenium Warning DEPRECATION while running ruby watir automation test script

Tags: watir, deprecated

Facing issue with Ruby watir.
script run successfully but showing the deprecated error in console.

**Error in Consoloe**
Selenium::Webdriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError is deprecated. Use Selenium::Webdriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError  instead.

**Script uses only this:**
    it "Should verify elements on exclusion refinement pop-up" do

```
    #expect(@b.text.include?'Markets').to eq(true)
    expect(@b.text.include?'Movement').to eq(true)
    expect(@b.text.include?'los Movement').to eq(true)
    expect(@b.text.include?'(Prepaid)').to eq(true)

end
```